# IMAP server proxy/forward

Tags: email, imap

I have multiple domains which all have an MX record for an extern mail hoster. Each of these domains has a different subdomain for the MX record.

What I would like to do is have my main domain serve as a IMAP login forward to the extern mail provider because only my main domain has a SSL certificiate.

So the server with the main domain would have to redirect the IMAP login to the correct subdomain (basically the MX record of the sub domains).

Is there a solution for this? I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: Okay, I just stumbled upon [Perdition](http://horms.net/projects/perdition/).
It seems to be what I'm looking for but I'm not quite sure yet.

Comment: Please limit stackoverflow questions to programming questions.  Your question would be better suited to serverfault.